BPMN Loop x times with event gateway
I want to model a sub-process, where a request to a customer is sent, and a reply is expected within 7 days. It should loop 2 times (for 3 requests total). Only after the 3rd waiting period, the customer should receive a notice, that their application is rejected.
The diagram is originally in German, thus this is just a quick translation for context in the BPMN.
Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:
This is an alternative (but this time in German), maybe this is a better way? The tasks are the same, i only removed the loop from the send task and added a conditional event to it instead of the last reminder xor gateway. Is the usage of the xor before the event gateway at the top correct?

